# json.net and wrong dates with +00:00 suffix

Tags: c#, json.net

I serialize objects having DateTime properties, like this: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(my_object)`, then on another machine I deserialize: `result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(r);`. And some dates are wrong. I've checked through fiddler that when date in json looks like this `Date=2014-11-29T18:41:41.1672899` then it's deserialized correctly, but every 10th or so entry looks like `Date=2014-11-29T18:55:39.1175417+00:00` (note the +00:00) and then it's deserialized as date shifted by two hours. Why is this and how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried setting `DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc` on `JsonSerializerSettings`?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov It worked! You could put this as an answer.

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set `DateTimeZoneHandling` to `DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc` on `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(r, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
  DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
});
```